# how to combine 2 .htaccess rewrites

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 2 different rewrites in my .htaccess file that I need to combine into 1.

The first redirects all requests to the `https://www` version of the website.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^w3studios\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The second gets all the post data and assigns to a variable.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I combine these to both work?

Thank-you

Comment: Is 2nd block part of `mywebsite.com` site root .htaccess?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've been using it so in my index.php I can use `$_GET('URL')` to return the value of the seo-friendly URL's. It's something i threw together by reading stuff on Google.

Comment: Ok need more details. What is purpose of first `301` redirect? Are both sites pointing to same host?

Comment: the first one makes it so if you go to `http://mywebsite.com` or `www.mywebsite.com` it redirects you to `https://www.mywebsite.com`. That way there isn't multiple versions of the website for search engines to index. It makes sure everyone is using the `https://www.` version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this combined set of rules in your site:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.